# how to take in input of every other line

Tags: python, input

say there was an input like so:

```
3
33 2
44 4
55 5
```

I tried

```py
n = int(input())

for i in range(n):
  n, m = map(int, input().split())
```

but since there is a space in between it doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe use splitlines() instead of split()

Answer (score -1):

it's probably much easier to

- take inputs until the input is empty instead of asking how many there will be in advance
- use a comprehension `map()` to collect the values (though your map works fine for me! `map(int, line.split())`)

```py
collection = []
while True:
    line = input()
    if not line.strip():
        break
    collection.append([int(x) for x in line.split()])
```